# JApplet Textfield/jbutton/nested loop program, create a wall, input number of rows in textfield

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, japplet

I am currently using `JCreator`, and can not find what is wrong with my code, for some reason its not reading what i input in the `JTextField`. I am not looking to change my code drastically, if any1 could just point out what i did wrong, or give me some code examples of what it should look like, that would be great.  again, not looking for "this is better then this" when they do the same thing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Wall extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    double count;
    Boolean Submit = false;
    JButton btn1;
    JTextField  tf,field;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 575;
    int x1 = 50;
    int y1 = 25;
    int textnumber;
    Random randomNum = new Random();//initialize random variable
    int count2;

    public void init() {

        setLayout( new FlowLayout( ) );
        tf = new JTextField(5);
        field = new JTextField( "<===== Enter Brick Rows 1-20", 16 );   
        add( tf );  
        add( field );
        btn1 = new JButton("Submit");
        add(btn1);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        if (event.getSource()== btn1){
            Submit = true;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, double BrickNumbers) {

        super.paint(g);
        while(Submit == true){
            DrawBrick(g,BrickNumbers);
        }
    }

    public void DrawBrick(Graphics g, double BrickNumbers){

        String Value = tf.getText();
        BrickNumbers = Double.parseDouble(Value);

        if(Submit == true){
            count = BrickNumbers;
            for(double count = BrickNumbers; ((count>=1) && (count <=20)); count--){

                int d = 1+ randomNum.nextInt(255);//get d variable
                int e = 1+ randomNum.nextInt(255);//get e variable
                int f = 1+ randomNum.nextInt(255);//get f variable
                Color randomcolor = new Color(d,e,f);
                g.setColor(randomcolor);
                g.fillRect(x, y, x1, y1);
                g.fillRect(x+ 50, y, x1, y1);
                g.fillRect(x+100, y, x1, y1);
                g.fillRect(x+150, y, x1, y1);
                g.fillRect(x+200, y, x1, y1);
                g.fillRect(x+250, y, x1, y1);   
                y = y - 25;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and stick to them

Answer (score 5):

You've got some bad code in your painting method including:

- you've got a while (true) loop in  your `paint(...)` method which will lock your GUI and prevent it from responding to *anything*.
- You're trying to read in from the JTextField in a method called from the paint method. You should never have program logic in your painting code or in methods it calls.
- You shouldn't be overriding `paint(...)` of a JApplet to begin with but rather `paintComponent(...)` in a JPanel that the JApplet holds.
- Consider adding code to read the JTextField(s) in your actionPerformed method as that seems to be the best place for this logic.

**Edit**

- Your paint method won't ever get called since it isn't a true overload of JApplet's paint method. Yours has 2 parameters and a paint method should only have one.
- In your actionPerformed method, get the value from the JTextField,
- convert it into an int with `Integer.parseInt(...)` not a double since you're never going to draw a fraction of a brick
- and with the int obtained set an int class field, perhaps called brickCount or something like that, and then call repaint().
- In your JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method (which like paint should only have one parameter, Graphics), call `paintBricks()`, and have this method use the brickCount field value to decide how many bricks to paint.
- Never call `repaint()` from within `paint(...)` `paintComponent(...)` or from any methods called from within these methods.

**Edit 2**

Here's an example that doesn't do what your program needs to do, but illustrates how to get information from a JTextField and use it in a drawing:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleApplet extends JApplet {
   @Override
   public void init() {
      getContentPane().add(new SimpleAppletMainPanel());
   }
}

class SimpleAppletMainPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final Color CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.red.darker();
   private static final int CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
   private static final int GAP = 3;
   private static final Stroke CIRCLE_STROKE = new BasicStroke((float)CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH);
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
   private JButton myButton = new JButton("Submit");
   private int count = 0;

   public SimpleAppletMainPanel() {
      ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
               count = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
               repaint();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      };
      myButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
      textField.addActionListener(actionListener);
      add(new JLabel("Enter a number, 1-10:"));
      add(textField);
      add(myButton);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         drawCircle(g, i);
      }
   }

   private void drawCircle(Graphics g, int layer) {
      int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
      int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
      int radius = layer * (CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH + GAP) + GAP;
      int x = centerX - radius ;
      int y = centerY - radius;

      Graphics2D g2b = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2b.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2b.setStroke(CIRCLE_STROKE);

      g2b.setColor(CIRCLE_COLOR);
      g2b.drawOval(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);

      g2b.dispose();
   }
}
```

This will result in the following:
[image][image]

Comment: okay, i understand everything except the overriding paint. also i am a bit confused as to where i should call the DrawBricks Method? otherwise it wont ever be called.  is this what should b in action listener also? im moderately new to java                                           if (event.getText() == tf){         
   String Value = tf.getText();
  BrickNumbers = Double.parseDouble(Value);
  }

Comment: @user1547182: You edit your original question and place the code in there. Please take pains to format it well as you don't want to make it hard for others to read and understand your code.

Comment: Take look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/, in particular, the "Performing Custom Painting" section

Comment: @user1547182: see example program to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee (Pulling my hair) :-) , as I ran through the code provided, I realized, the `init()` method is not using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)/invokeAndWait()`, so seems like the example is missing the EDT part :(